# cons a symbol with a variable and return as a symbol

Tags: list, backquote

How can I make `fun2` return as the same as `fun1`?

```
(defun fun1 ()
  '((hello . "test"))) ; <= returns ((hello . "test"))

(defun fun2 (str)
  '((hello . str))) ; <= this is wrong! should return ((hello . "test"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```lisp
(defun fun2 (str)
  `((hello . ,str)))
```

See the backquote section of the Emacs manual:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html

Comment: Or `(defun fun2 (str) (list (cons 'hello str)))`. It doesn't hurt to look behind the "magic" of backquoting.